# storm-YARN : Topology submitted but no supervisor nodes assigned

Tags: hadoop-yarn, hadoop-streaming, apache-storm

I'm running WordCount storm TOPOLOGY (https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter/).

I'm launching this topology via storm yarn, but it's not running any worker nodes. In the storm ui I cannot see any supervisor nodes assigned. In my code I've configured to start three worker nodes.
Do we need to do something else to get the supervisors started?

I also looked at nimbus.log, stderr, stdout & ui.log there are no signs of error.

`storm jar target/storm-starter-0.9.3-rc2-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar storm.starter.WordCountTopology TEST-WC-TOPO`

`1045 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.StormSubmitter - Successfully uploaded topology jar to assigned location: storm-local/nimbus/inbox/stormjar-4a08ebf7-022c-4b22-86be-1efc6e8f6be0.jar
1046 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.StormSubmitter - Submitting topology WCT in distributed mode with conf {"topology.workers":3,"topology.debug":true}
1438 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.StormSubmitter - Finished submitting topology: WCT`

Comment: If I start a supervisor on my local machine via `storm supervisor` nimbus assigns it to the present topology and it starts working as expected.

I'm not sure why nimbus is not **starting** (__or trying to do so__) the supervisor nodes by itself.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Did you get the answer ?

Comment: @sahu did you solve it ?